# Azure - Troubleshooting a failed deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Is there any mechanism I can use to troubleshoot a failed deployment? The output that Azure gives me is massively unsatisfactory.

```
"Role has encountered an error and has stopped. Unhandled Exception DirectoryNotFoundException."
```

I'm trying to automatically deploy via msbuild and powershell and the problem im encountering is curious as the deploy works perfectly when I publish from Visual Studio building the same .sln.

The service configuration and definition is precisely the same in both instances so I'm starting to have real difficulties in understanding the actual problem. I've checked some of the [most common problems](http://blog.toddysm.com/2010/01/windows-azure-deployment-stuck-in-initializing-busy-stopping-why.html) and I don't appear to be suffering from any of them.

Additionally.... its a website.... so as far as I'm aware its not possible for any of my code to be creating unhandled exceptions at initialisation.... is it?

Any suggestions or information how to perform a better diagnosis would be appreciated. I'm obviously doing *something* wrong in my publish process but its really tricky to track down the problem without adequate diagnostics here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable remote desktop, log in to the machine and check event log.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx

You can also set up [Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx) that will ship event log entries to Azure Storage so you don't have to remote desktop.

Comment: takes a ton of digging once you're in but that's given me more information. Thanks! :)